# Win2012-R2: Routing and remote access services on EC2: Does not come up

Tags: windows

I am new to RRAS on Win2012-R2.

Doing my learning in an ec2 instance (the ultimate rollout will also be to an ec2 instance).

Added the role, no errors, rebooted box, run mmc, and RRAS shows the red/stopped state. Did the configure wiz, it STILL shows the red/stopped state. In services, the RRAS service is disabled.

Enabled and started the service, but the RRAS config still fails to show the expected sub-tree items.

What am I missing?

(Goal is to vpn to this machine from off site to copy files to this machine, and perhaps access sql server on this machine)

Inspection of the event log shows:

```
Failed to apply IP Security on port VPN0-0 because of error: A certificate could not be found.  Connections that use the L2TP protocol over IPSec require the installation of a machine certificate, also known as a computer certificate..  No calls will be accepted to this port.

Remote Access Connection Manager failed to start because the Protocol engine [IKEv2] failed to initialize. The request is not supported.
```

This is a stand alone server, in EC2, not part of a domain (nor possible to make it part of a domain). The docs I see on certificates seem to require a DC or such. What to do for a standard server? (And must the cert come from a real CA and cost $?)

Comment: Does the event log have any interesting and relevant information?

Comment: @KatherineVillyard Good call! Post enhanced with that info. Thank you!